# Update a programmatically defined ASP Literal on PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm at my wits' end here. I'm creating an order tracking manager for the backend of our online store. I've managed to create an HTML table by `StringBuilder`ing together values from our SQL database with HTML tags into one long String that I then set as the text of an ASP `Literal`.

The table contains `<input>` fields to allow the user to change order data. I've also managed to get a button working that sends the data from those input fields into our database. But here's where my problem arises:

No matter what I try, when the user presses the button, the page reloads but doesn't update the table data. That is, the `Literal`'s text is exactly the same as it was when the page was first loaded. The error messages do show, if there are any. And if I refresh the page, the new data appears – but that causes the error messages to disappear.

How can I get the new data to show up? I have a feeling I'm misunderstanding something fundamental about `ViewState` or `Page_Load` or one of those things.

Here's my code:

ASP:

```
<asp:Content ID="PageContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlContent" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="managerUpdate">
        <h1><asp:Literal ID="ltResultsHeading" runat="server"></asp:Literal></h1>
        <%-- Header and other miscellaneous --%>
        <table id="order-table" style="table-layout:fixed;" class="table table-condensed table-bordered small text-center">
            <colgroup>
                <col style="width:7.5%"><col style="width:10%"><col style="width:20%"><col style="width:20%"><col style="width:20%"><col style="width:7.5%"><col style="width:7.5%">
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Order &#8470;</th>
                    <th>Conf. &#8470;</th>
                    <th>Stage</th>
                    <th>Est'd ship date</th>
                    <th>Shippped via</th>
                    <th>Send update email?</th>
                    <th>Save chngs?</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
                <asp:Literal ID="ltTableData" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <asp:Button ID="btnSaveAndEmail" Text="Save and Send Emails" runat="server" OnClientClick="return createArrays();" CssClass="btn btn-primary btnSaveAndEmail"></asp:Button>

        <asp:Literal ID="ltErrors" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        <br>
        <asp:TextBox 
            TextMode="multiline" ID="PhoneUpdates" 
            CssClass="PhoneUpdates" runat="server">
        </asp:TextBox>
        <br>

        <script>
        // jQuery to validate data changed in the inputs in the table, create delimited strings with data values, and put them in the TextBox above.
        </script>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Codebehind C#:

```
using // (Various)

namespace AspDotNetStorefront
{
    public partial class OrderManagerPage : SkinBase
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Here I get data from the SQL database.
            // Then,

            StringBuilder phoneOrdersHtml = new StringBuilder();
            // Build a series of HTML table rows with the data retrieved.
            // Finally,
            ltTableData.Text = phoneOrdersHtml.ToString();
        }

        void btnSaveAndEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Takes values from PhoneUpdates TextBox and creates SQL update query, then executes it.
            // If errors are returned, places them into ltErrors.Text.
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at how WebForms handles the Page life cycle: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#general_page_lifecycle_stages

Your Page_Load event fires first then your button click event. In your case, you are setting the text first, then running the SQL update query so it seems like nothing has changed.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            WriteTable();
        }
    }

    protected void Unnamed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Run SQL stuff
        WriteTable();
    }

    private void WriteTable()
    {
        StringBuilder phoneOrdersHtml = new StringBuilder();
        ltTableData.Text = phoneOrdersHtml.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd read no end of long, complicated articles about the Page life cycle, but I always managed to miss the part where click event handlers are handled _after_ the Page_Load. It's working beautifully now.